# steady state or equilibrium

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, stability-in-odes

I need to find the equilibrium point of the following system of equation: 
$ds/dt = u - asi - bsw - us$ 
 $di/dt = asi + bsw - (u + g)i$  
 $dw/dt = e(i - w)$ 
 
  I found that $$s = \frac{u}{ai + bw + u}$$ when I plug into $i$ that's where I got confused. I have the following 
$aiu + bwu -i(u+g)(ai+bw+u) = 0$ 
and I don't know what to do. Can somebody help me to figure out the value of $i$ with what I actually tried?

Comment: These are supposed to be differential equations?  So the left sides are not $s, i, w$ but rather $ds/dt$, $di/dt$ and $dw/dt$?   And the other letters represent parameters?

Comment: @RobertIsrael you are correct! Thanks for the correction, I already fixed it. Can you help me with the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the right sides of all three equations to be $0$.

Start with the last equation: assuming $e \ne 0$, you need $i=w$.  Then the other equations say

$$ \eqalign{ u - (a + b) s w - u s &= 0\cr
             (a + b) s w - (u + g) w &= 0\cr}$$
The second of these factors nicely, and says either $w=0$ or $s = (u+g)/(a+b)$.  If $w=0$ and $u \ne 0$, the first equation says $s=1$.  If $s = (u+g)/(a+b)$, the first equation says ...